# Conflicting Javascript between Media Capture and OnScreen Keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling, codepen

Disclaimer: I am brand new to Javascript, CSS, and HTML but I have been browsing the internet taking snippets of code and putting them together for a project I am working on.

Right now I am stuck because I can't figure out why, when I enable the javascript for the media capture, the onscreen keyboard goes away. There doesn't seem to be anything in conflict as far as I can tell.

Here is a link to the codepen: 
https://codepen.io/sterlingbutters/pen/LJryzr

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/css/index.css">
</head>

<body>

<div onmousedown="WhichButton(event)"
     id = "information"> 
  Click the video with one of your mouse buttons to<br> return a number.

  <video autoplay
         class = "box"
         id = "screen"></video>

  <p>
  0 = The left mouse button<br>
  1 = The middle mouse button<br>
  2 = The right mouse button
  </p>

  <p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 8, and earlier,<br> returns another result:</p>

  <p>
  1 = The left mouse button<br>
  4 = The middle mouse button<br>
  2 = The right mouse button
  </p>

<!-- Position -->
  <div id="position"></div>
<!-- Position -->

<!-- Click -->
  <p id="demo"></p>
<!-- Click -->

</div>

<!-- Keyboard -->
  <div id="keyboard">
  <input class="input" 
         size="125"
         placeholder="Tap on the virtual keyboard or type to enter text"/>

  <div class="simple-keyboard"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/index.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </div>
<!-- Keyboard -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#screen{ 
  position: absolute;
  height: 120%;
  width: 100%;
  left: -119%;
  top: -15%;
}

#information{ 
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 60%;
  top: 5%;
}

#keyboard{ 
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  top: 55%;
}
```

Here is the Js:

```
// Media Capture
// // FROM HERE
// const constraints = {
//   video: true
// };

// const video = document.querySelector('video');

// navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
//   then((stream) => {video.srcObject = stream});

// const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
// const audioSelect = document.querySelector('select#audioSource');
// const videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');

// navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
//   .then(gotDevices).then(getStream).catch(handleError);

// audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
// videoSelect.onchange = getStream;

// function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
//   for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
//     const deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
//     const option = document.createElement('option');
//     option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
//     if (deviceInfo.kind === 'audioinput') {
//       option.text = deviceInfo.label ||
//         'microphone ' + (audioSelect.length + 1);
//       audioSelect.appendChild(option);
//     } else if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
//       option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'camera ' +
//         (videoSelect.length + 1);
//       videoSelect.appendChild(option);
//     } else {
//       console.log('Found another kind of device: ', deviceInfo);
//     }
//   }
// }

// function getStream() {
//   if (window.stream) {
//     window.stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
//       track.stop();
//     });
//   }

//   const constraints = {
//     audio: {
//       deviceId: {exact: audioSelect.value}
//     },
//     video: {
//       deviceId: {exact: videoSelect.value}
//     }
//   };

//   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).
//     then(gotStream).catch(handleError);
// }

// function gotStream(stream) {
//   window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
//   videoElement.srcObject = stream;
// }

// function handleError(error) {
//   console.error('Error: ', error);
// }
// // TO HERE

// Click
function WhichButton(event) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You pressed button: " + event.button;
}

// Position
var position = document.getElementById("position");

// Creating function that will tell the position of cursor
// PageX and PageY will getting position values and show them in P
function tellPos(p){
  position.innerHTML = 'Position X : ' + p.pageX + '<br />Position Y : ' + p.pageY;
}
addEventListener('mousemove', tellPos, false);

// OnScreen Keyboard
// https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard

let Keyboard = window.SimpleKeyboard.default;

let myKeyboard = new Keyboard({
  onChange: input => onChange(input),
  onKeyPress: button => onKeyPress(button)
});

function onChange(input) {
  document.querySelector(".input").value = input;
  console.log("Input changed", input);
}

function onKeyPress(button) {
  console.log("Button pressed", button);
}

// Normal Keyboard
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){

  // Gives Key Code: event.keyCode;
  // Gives Actual Key: event.key
  document.querySelector(".input").value += event.key;
  console.log("Input changed", input);
} );
```

For the above 3 snippets, the onscreen keyboard, mouse position, and mouse clicks are all tracked and displayed.

[image]

However, by uncommenting the first section of the Js ("FROM HERE" - "TO HERE"), the media capture/stream becomes visible but the onscreen keyboard goes away.

[image]

There is some weird styling that is pulled from an external source an I'm not sure if that has something to do with it?

Please help, and thanks in advance!

EDIT: I believe these are the contents of index.js:

```
/*!
 * 
 *   simple-keyboard v2.3.26
 *   https://github.com/hodgef/simple-keyboard
 * 
 *   Copyright (c) Francisco Hodge (https://github.com/hodgef)
 * 
 *   This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 *   LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *   
 */
!function(t,n){"object"===typeof exports&&"object"===typeof module?module.exports=n():"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define([],n):"object"===typeof exports?exports.SimpleKeyboard=n():t.SimpleKeyboard=n()}(this,function(){return function(t){function n(o){if(e[o])return e[o].exports;var i=e[o]={i:o,l:!1,exports:{}};return t[o].call(i.exports,i,i.exports,n),i.l=!0,i.exports}var e={};return n.m=t,n.c=e,n.d=function(t,e,o){n.o(t,e)||Object.defineProperty(t,e,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:o})},n.n=function(t){var e=t&&t.__esModule?function(){return t.default}:function(){return t};return n.d(e,"a",e),e},n.o=function(t,n){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,n)},n.p="",n(n.s=0)}([function(t,n,e){t.exports=e(1)},function(t,n,e){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(n,"__esModule",{value:!0});var o=e(2);n.default=o.a},function(t,n,e){"use strict";function o(t,n){if(!(t instanceof n))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}var i=e(3),a=(e.n(i),e(4)),s=e(5),r="function"===typeof Symbol&&"symbol"===typeof Symbol.iterator?function(t){return typeof t}:function(t){return t&&"function"===typeof Symbol&&t.constructor===Symbol&&t!==Symbol.prototype?"symbol":typeof t},u=function t(){o(this,t),c.call(this);var n="string"===typeof(arguments.length<=0?void 0:arguments[0])?arguments.length<=0?void 0:arguments[0]:".simple-keyboard",e="object"===r(arguments.length<=0?void 0:arguments[0])?arguments.length<=0?void 0:arguments[0]:arguments.length<=1?void 0:arguments[1];e||(e={}),this.keyboardDOM=document.querySelector(n),this.options=e,this.options.layoutName=this.options.layoutName||"default",this.options.theme=this.options.theme||"hg-theme-default",this.options.inputName=this.options.inputName||"default",this.input={},this.input[this.options.inputName]="",this.keyboardDOMClass=n.split(".").join(""),this.keyboardDOM?this.render():console.error('"'+n+'" was not found in the DOM.')},c=function(){var t=this;this.handleButtonClicked=function(n){var e=t.options.debug;if("{//}"===n)return!1;"function"===typeof t.options.onKeyPress&&t.options.onKeyPress(n);var o={newLineOnEnter:!0===t.options.newLineOnEnter};t.input[t.options.inputName]||(t.input[t.options.inputName]="");var i=s.a.getUpdatedInput(n,t.input[t.options.inputName],o);t.input[t.options.inputName]!==i&&(t.input[t.options.inputName]=i,e&&console.log("Input changed:",t.input),"function"===typeof t.options.onChange&&t.options.onChange(t.input[t.options.inputName])),e&&console.log("Key pressed:",n)},this.clearInput=function(n){n=n||t.options.inputName,t.input[t.options.inputName]=""},this.getInput=function(n){return n=n||t.options.inputName,t.input[t.options.inputName]},this.setInput=function(n,e){e=e||t.options.inputName,t.input[e]=n},this.setOptions=function(n){n=n||{},t.options=Object.assign(t.options,n),t.render()},this.clear=function(){t.keyboardDOM.innerHTML="",t.keyboardDOM.className=t.keyboardDOMClass},this.render=function(){t.clear();var n=t.options.layout?"hg-layout-custom":"hg-layout-"+t.options.layoutName,e=t.options.layout||a.a.getLayout(t.options.layoutName),o={};Array.isArray(t.options.buttonTheme)&&t.options.buttonTheme.forEach(function(t){if(t.buttons&&t.class){var n=t.buttons.split(" ");Array.isArray(n)&&n.forEach(function(n){var e=o[n];o[n]=e?e+" "+t.class:t.class})}else console.warn('buttonTheme row is missing the "buttons" or the "class". Please check the documentation.')}),t.keyboardDOM.className+=" "+t.options.theme+" "+n,e[t.options.layoutName].forEach(function(n){var e=n.split(" "),i=document.createElement("div");i.className+="hg-row",e.forEach(function(n){var e=s.a.getButtonClass(n),a=o[n],r=s.a.getButtonDisplayName(n,t.options.display),u=document.createElement("div");u.className+="hg-button "+e+(a?" "+a:""),u.onclick=function(){return t.handleButtonClicked(n)};var c=document.createElement("span");c.innerHTML=r,u.appendChild(c),i.appendChild(u),"function"===typeof t.options.onInit&&t.options.onInit()}),t.keyboardDOM.appendChild(i)})}};n.a=u},function(t,n){},function(t,n,e){"use strict";function o(t,n){if(!(t instanceof n))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}var i=function t(){o(this,t)};i.getLayout=function(t){return"qwerty"===t?{default:["` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - = {bksp}","{tab} q w e r t y u i o p [ ] \\","{lock} a s d f g h j k l ; ' {enter}","{shift} z x c v b n m , . / {shift}",".com @ {space}"],shift:["~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + {bksp}","{tab} Q W E R T Y U I O P { } |",'{lock} A S D F G H J K L : " {enter}',"{shift} Z X C V B N M < > ? {shift}",".com @ {space}"]}:"numeric"===t?{default:["1 2 3","4 5 6","7 8 9","{//} 0 {bksp}"]}:i.getLayout("qwerty")},n.a=i},function(t,n,e){"use strict";function o(t,n){if(!(t instanceof n))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}var i=function(){function t(t,n){for(var e=0;e<n.length;e++){var o=n[e];o.enumerable=o.enumerable||!1,o.configurable=!0,"value"in o&&(o.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(t,o.key,o)}}return function(n,e,o){return e&&t(n.prototype,e),o&&t(n,o),n}}(),a=function(){function t(){o(this,t)}return i(t,null,[{key:"normalizeString",value:function(t){var n=void 0;return n="@"===t?"at":","===t?"comma":"."===t?"dot":"\\"===t?"backslash":"/"===t?"fordardslash":"*"===t?"asterisk":"&"===t?"ampersand":"$"===t?"dollarsign":"="===t?"equals":"+"===t?"plus":"-"===t?"minus":"'"===t?"apostrophe":";"===t?"colon":"["===t?"openbracket":"]"===t?"closebracket":"//"===t?"emptybutton":"",n?" hg-button-"+n:""}},{key:"getDefaultDiplay",value:function(){return{"{bksp}":"backspace","{enter}":"< enter","{shift}":"shift","{s}":"shift","{tab}":"tab","{lock}":"caps","{accept}":"Submit","{space}":" ","{//}":" "}}}]),t}();a.getButtonClass=function(t){var n=t.includes("{")&&"{//}"!==t?"functionBtn":"standardBtn",e=t.replace("{","").replace("}","");return"hg-"+n+("standardBtn"===n?a.normalizeString(e):" hg-button-"+e)},a.getButtonDisplayName=function(t,n){return n=n||a.getDefaultDiplay(),n[t]||t},a.getUpdatedInput=function(t,n,e){var o=n,i=e.newLineOnEnter;if("{bksp}"===t&&o.length>0){o=o.slice(-2).match(/([\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g)?o.slice(0,-2):o.slice(0,-1)}else"{space}"===t?o+=" ":"{tab}"===t?o+="\t":"{enter}"===t&&i?o+="\n":t.includes("{")||t.includes("}")||(o+=t);return o},n.a=a}])});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Comment: Could you edit this post and include the contents of `<script src="src/index.js"></script>`? Codepen gives a DOMException of 'Requested device not found'. However running locally there's a reference error with a missing `getStream`. But I'm also getting TypeErrors with the toJSON call

Comment: Edit posted; I haven't tried running locally yet and I believe the Js is supposed to allow you to choose 'requested device' and if none are available then obviously nothing is streamed which is what happens on my desktop as opposed to my laptop

Comment: Hey @SterlingButters, thanks for using simple-keyboard! I see that you've resolved this issue, but if you have any questions about the plugin feel free to reach out ! I added some sandbox examples that you can fork should you want to experiment: https://codesandbox.io/u/hodgef/sandboxes. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not created the elements for `audioSelect` and `videoSelect`.

Either make the element (if you took this from an example look there) or just remove lines 18 and 19.

```
//audioSelect.onchange = getStream;
//videoSelect.onchange = getStream;
```

Comment: Omg it works, thank you! Can you explain in more detail why that would hide the keyboard (for someone brand new to js)?

Comment: There is no element "select#videoSelect" so the variable videoSelect is null. Then trying to assign videoSelect.onchange causes an error because it is null. This causes the code to stop and never run the part that opens the keyboard.